# If it's possible if I want to direct to another page by using Javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a menu which has 3 option : Coffee, Tea and Food

My expectation is if clicking `Coffee` I will go direct `home.php` with url parameter that store value `1`

This code is in php file

```
<script>        
    function changeType(numTab){
        changetab(numTab);
            if(numTab == 1){
                <?php 
                    header("Location: home.php?type=1");  ?>
            }
            else if(numTab == 2){
                <?php 
                    header("Location: home.php?type=2"); ?>
            }
            else if(numTab == 3){
                <?php 
                    header("Location: home.php?type=3"); ?>
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript and PHP exist in different realms...

Comment: Instead of the PHP header calls, can use `window.location = 'home.php? type=1';` in the JavaScript to achieve the same.

Comment: Thak you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to use JavaScript to change the current URL and redirect to home.php with a specific query parameter based on the value of numTab. Your code attempt mixes PHP and JavaScript, but it won't work as expected because PHP is server-side, and JavaScript is client-side.

To achieve the desired behavior, you can use JavaScript alone to handle the redirection. Here's how you can do it:

```
<script>
    function changeType(numTab) {
        if (numTab >= 1 && numTab <= 3) {
            window.location.href = `home.php?type=${numTab}`;
        }
    }
</script>
```

With this code, when you call the changeType function with a specific numTab value, it will set the window.location.href to the desired URL with the appropriate query parameter, effectively redirecting the user to the home.php page with the specified type parameter.